# Check if value exist in datatable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

i have sql command and I save values into datatable.

```
con.Open();
cmd0.CommandText = "Select ......";
DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
dtbl.Load(cmd0.ExecuteReader());
```

And i have value String Name.
I need to know, if the value in String Name is in the datatable dtbl...It is possible?

Comment: Maybe you could use a SqlDataReader to get the information, another stack question explains how to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018114/read-data-from-sqldatareader

Comment: Can you share the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's only a single value returned, you could do this:

```
string value = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Anyway the `DataTable` has a collection `.Rows` of DataRow elements.Each `DataRow` corresponds to a record row in your database.

If you want to access a single value, do something like this:

```
   foreach(DataRow row in dtbl.Rows)
     { 
         if(row["ColumnName"].ToString()=="Name")
         {
         }      
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, you can use [DataTable.Compute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like as follows.

```
string valueToSearch = "lorem";
string columnName = "Name";
int count =
    (int) dtbl.Compute(string.Format("count({0})", columnName),
        string.Format("{0} like '{1}'", columnName, valueToSearch));
```

Comment: Now i have this error: Syntax Error: Before the LIKE operator is missing operand.

Comment: You can use `=` instead of `like`. where clause should be written here just like in a SQL sentence (`select count(Name) from dtbl where Name like 'yourName'`). Additionally the answer above, that loops in dtbl.Rows and checks the equality, is costful, dtbl.Compute method already does what you needed.