# SQL Server error - Missing Data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a problem with this function...

```
public Veiculo getVehiclebyMatricula(string MAT)
{
     Veiculo V = new Veiculo();
     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from Veiculo where matricula =@mat;",CNManager.getConnection());
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mat", MAT);
     SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

     if (dr.HasRows)
     {
         V._id = dr.GetInt32(0); //HERE
         V.marca = dr.GetString(1);
         V.modelo = dr.GetString(2);
         V.matricula = dr.GetString(3);
         V.estado = dr.GetString(4);
         V.preco = dr.GetInt32(5);
         V.cilindrada = dr.GetInt32(6);
         V.image = dr.GetString(7);
         V.id_tipo = dr.GetInt32(8);

         dr.Close();
         return V;
      }
      return V;
   }
```

the error that spawns says "Reading not valid when data is not present.."

Comment: What error you are getting . tell us in detail.

Comment: Reading not valid when data is not present...

Comment: You are closing two times,  dr.Close()!, try to put in try catch finally{ dr.Close();}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# has a handy statement that closes and releases resources automatically: the `using` command. It does so, even if the `using` block is left prematurely because of an error or because of a `return` or `break` statement. You were closing the connection twice. In my example below, I use the `using`-statement in order to close the connection, the command and the reader.

You should not keep the connection open. This potentially consumes resources over a long time. Open it and close it (with `using`) each time you need a connection. The connection pool automatically keeps connections open for some time, so that the "physical" connection will not be constantly closed and reopened.

Before a record can be accessed you must move to the first (or next) record with `dr.Read()`. This method also returns a Boolean value telling you whether a record was there and whether the operation could be performed. Use `dr.Read()` instead of `dr.HasRows`.

I am also using a command parameter, which is both easier and safer as stitching the command together with string operations.

```
public Veiculo getVehiclebyMatricula(string MAT)
{
    Veiculo V = new Veiculo();
    query = "select * from Veiculo where matricula = @m";

    using (SqlConnection conn = CNManager.getConnection())
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, conn)) {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m", MAT);
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader()) {
            if (dr.Read()) {
                V._id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["_id"]);
                V.marca = dr["marca"].ToString();
                V.modelo = dr["modelo"].ToString();
                V.matricula = dr["matricula"].ToString();
                V.estado = Convert.ToChar(dr["estado"]);
                V.preco = Convert.ToInt32(dr["preco"]);
                V.cilindrada = Convert.ToInt32(dr["cilindrada"]);
                V.image = dr["_src"].ToString();
                V.id_tipo = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id_tipo"]);
            }
        }
    }
    return V;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should really use parametrized queries and not just concatenate strings like this, because this opens doors for SQL injection. Try instead:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from Veiculo where matricula =@mat;",CNManager.getConnection());
command.Parameters.Add("@mat", MAT);
command.Execute...
```

Beside that you are closing your connection twice.

I would suggest to put your SQL connection object into a using block to make sure it's getting closed and drop your lines where you are closing your connection instead.

Comment: Didnt Work... but thnks for the query syntax :)

Comment: @Maverick Can you tell me why it didnt work, maybe I can help you.

Answer (score 2):

You must call `dr.Read()` ( `SqlDataReader.Read()` ) and check if it returns true before accessing your dr properties.

Answer (score 1):

You are closing two times, dr.Close()!, the message is saying that cannot read while data not present, since you closed it, try to put in this way:

```
try{
 ...
 } catch(){
 } finally
 { 
     dr.Close();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as replacing string concatenation with SQLParameters as other answers. The return data you need to call  [`Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx) on the `DataReader`.

Take a look at this question for an example of accessing the resultset: [Read data from SqlDataReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018114/read-data-from-sqldatareader)

Quick snippet:

```
using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        var myString = rdr.GetString(0); //The 0 stands for "the 0'th column", so the first column of the result.
        // Do somthing with this rows string, for example to put them in to a list
        listDeclaredElsewhere.Add(myString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had some problems handling SQL in C#/ASP.NET, so I always add use the Entity Framework. It is way easier to manipulate.

Here's how your problem would look with the Entity Framework...

```
public Veiculo getVehiclebyMatricula(string MAT)
{
    Veiculo V = new Veiculo();
    var context = new Entities(); //The name 'Entities' is up to you
    var dr = context.Veiculo.Where(m => m.matricula = MAT);
    foreach (var r in dr) {
        V._id = r._id;
        V.marca = r.marca;
        V.modelo = r.modelo;
        V.matricula = r.matricula
        V.estado = r.estado
        V.preco = r.preco;
        V.cilindrada = r.cilindrada;
        V.image = r._src
        V.id_tipo = r.id_tipo
    }
    context.Close();
}
```

Lemme know if this works out for you.