# Retrieve table names

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to retrieve the names of the table from the local database I'm using.

This the code I've tried but it never goes through the foreach loop:

```
public void GetColumnNames()
    {
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.AlhusainSoundDBConnectionString);

        List<string> colns = new List<string>();

            try
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
            {
                colns.Add(dt.TableName);
                Console.WriteLine(dt.TableName);
            }
    }
```

So could anyone please suggest me how to do that correctly

Regards

Comment: Where did you fill your `ds` exactly? I don't see _any_ code to do that.

Comment: There's no code here that actually selects data from the database.  `foreach` won't iterate over an empty collection.

Answer (score 1):

To get table names you need to use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`

```
USE <your_database_name>
GO
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't done anything except open a connection to the database.  Your dataset has not been populated with any data.  My approach would be to use a SqlCommand object to execute the following SQL Statement and populate a SqlDataReader

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

So, the C# code might look something like this:

```
string sql = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES";

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.AlhusainSoundDBConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    con.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            // do something with each table
            string tableName= dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            // OR
            // string tableName = dr[0].ToString();
            // OR
            // string tableName = dr.GetString(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now how can I get the table names from the reader? @snow_FFFFFF

Comment: @AliAlhamaly During the `while` you get the data row by row and you just need to access the datareader as you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018114/read-data-from-sqldatareader

Comment: updated the answer with some detail on getting values from the reader