# Missing results when querying SQL Server from ASP.NET WebService

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, sqldatareader

Guys please I've tried almost everything I know and all possibilities that I can implement...

What happens is that when I make this select by proc or commandtext, my datareader returns only 3 records but I have 7 on the database with those parameters. 
If I mark those 3 as read and make a new requisition only 2 are sent back to me. Same again if there is only one, the last one is never brought back to me.

Here is my code

```
    public List<Documentos> GetDocumentosDisponiveisParaMotorista(string motoristaCpf, string veiculoPlaca,
        long transportadora)
    {
        var retorno = new List<Documentos>();

        var command = Banco.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.SelectDocumentos");
        AddInParameter(command, "@MotoristaCpf", motoristaCpf);
        AddInParameter(command, "@VeiculoPlaca", veiculoPlaca.ToUpper());
        AddInParameter(command, "@TransportadoraId", transportadora);

        //var command = Banco.GetSqlStringCommand("SELECT " +
        //                                        "TransportadoraId" +
        //                                        ", FilialSigla" +
        //                                        ", TipoDocumentoId" +
        //                                        ", Documento" +
        //                                        ", DocumentoSerie" +
        //                                        ", MotoristaCpf" +
        //                                        ", VeiculoPlaca" +
        //                                        ", DocumentoChave" +
        //                                        ", DocumentoTransporte" +
        //                                        ", TipoDocTransporte" +
        //                                        ", NumeroNotaFiscal" +
        //                                        ", DestinatarioCpfCnpj" +
        //                                        ", LocalEntregaId" +
        //                                        ", StatusId" +
        //                                        ", Comprovante" +
        //                                        ", Transmitido" +
        //                                        ", TransmitidoData" +
        //                                        ", DataCadastro" +
        //                                        ", DataAlteracao " +
        //                                        "FROM Documentos WITH(NOLOCK) " +
        //                                        "WHERE MotoristaCpf = @MotoristaCpf " +
        //                                        "AND VeiculoPlaca = @VeiculoPlaca " +
        //                                        "AND TransportadoraId = @TransportadoraId " +
        //                                        "AND Transmitido is null ");

        //command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MotoristaCpf", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 11, "MotoristaCpf"));
        //command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VeiculoPlaca", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 7, "VeiculoPlaca"));
        //command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TransportadoraId", SqlDbType.BigInt, 999999999, "TransportadoraId"));

        //command.Parameters["@MotoristaCpf"].Value = motoristaCpf;
        //command.Parameters["@VeiculoPlaca"].Value = veiculoPlaca.ToUpper();
        //command.Parameters["@TransportadoraId"].Value = transportadora;
        //command.Connection = Banco.CreateConnection();
        //command.Connection.Open();
        //command.CommandTimeout = 3600;

        using (var dataReader = Banco.ExecuteReader(command))
        {
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    retorno.Add(dataReader.Read() ? Preencher(dataReader) : null);
                }

                dataReader.Close();

        }
        return retorno;
    }
```

I'm using SQL Server 2005. This is a WebService code in asp.net C#. My connection is made using connectionstring. I don't use NHibernate and I'm using `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data`.

Comment: Your are advancing the reader twice, calling `Read()` twice. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Crowcoder mentions in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40867022/problens-whith-enterpriselibrary-and-sql-server-in-asp-net-webservices#comment68949440_40867022) your main problem is calling 
    `dataReader.Read()` twice. Take a look at this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018114/read-data-from-sqldatareader) to see how to use the `SqlDataReader.Read()` method.

Furthermore, there is no need for you to call `dataReader.Close();` as it will automatically be disposed of at the end of your [**using** block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Comment: Thank you you too guys, It was that, but that give another problem but alredy solved thanks