# MySQL equivalent of MS SQL code

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I have this part of project, written using MS SQL:

```
 selectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table1";
        var data_ar = selectCommand.ExecuteReader().Select(r =>
           new
           {
               Value1 = r["Value1"].ToString(),
               Value2 = r["Value2"].ToString(),
           })
           .ToList();
```

How can i change this code to make it work with MySqlConnection instead of SqlConnection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using MySQL like this code you need a nuget package that is used for interacting with MySQL server. I ma using this for 7 years [www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/7.0.7-m61](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/7.0.7-m61)

All code will be same, just namespace and classes will be changed. All will come with Prefix "My"

Comment: So, what should I do after installation of that package?

Comment: @Dan use Mysql.Data.Client and then start using class like MySQLConnection , MySQLCommand, MySQLDatareader. all will work same as SQL server but with prefix "My"

Comment: ok, I've used MySql.Data.MySqlClient, but I still have error on selectCommand.ExecuteReader().Select: "MySqlDataReader does not contain a definition for "Select".

Comment: @Dan yup, many things will be missing in Mysql. for common code refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4018147/713789