# While filling comboBox with data from database, i created SqlDataReader. I wish to retrieve a column with product names

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqldatareader

This is the code.

```
void ProdFill()
{
    string coninfo = "datasource=DESKTOP-1F4329L;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
    string query = "select * from prodTest.product;";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(coninfo);
    SqlCommand cmdDb = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    SqlDataReader myReader;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        myReader = cmdDb.ExecuteReader();
        while(myReader.Read())
        {
            string prodname = myReader.GetString("pname");
            comboBox2.Items.Add(prodname);
        }
    }
}
```

It's giving an error at:

```
string prodname = myReader.GetString("pname");
```

stating that

> it has invalid arguments. Cannot convert from string to int.

Comment: please check through breakpoint.what is the generated value is given by prodname?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018114/read-data-from-sqldatareader

Comment: I tried ToString(), its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Pass column index inside GetString()

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following approaches

If you want to get data by column name then you can go with

```
string prodname = myReader["pname"].ToString();
```

If you know index of column then you can go with

```
   string prodname = myReader.GetString(0); //you can replace 0 with index of column
```

After getting data from `myReader`, you can add it to combobox

```
comboBox2.Items.Add(prodname);
```