# C# - I need to return a dictionary list of all the keys and values but I am only getting one value returned

Tags: c#

```
namespace SECDataPurge
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Dictionary<Guid, string>> companies = new List<Dictionary<Guid, string>>();
            companies = GetCompanies();

            foreach(var company in companies)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(company.Keys.FirstOrDefault() + " " + company.Values.FirstOrDefault());                
            
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static List<Dictionary<Guid, string>> GetCompanies()
        {

            List<Dictionary<Guid, string>> companies = new List<Dictionary<Guid, string>>();

            //open a connection using connection string 
            //get companies by call SP
            //return companies 
            using (SqlConnection conn = new 
            SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppDbConnectionString"]))

            {
                string query = "SELECT id, [name] FROM [dbo].[company];";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = query;
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                    conn.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        reader.Read();
                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            Dictionary<Guid, string> company = new Dictionary<Guid, string>();
                            Guid companyGuid = new Guid();
                            string companyName = string.Empty;

                            if (reader["id"] != DBNull.Value)
                            {
                                companyGuid = (Guid)reader["id"];
                               
                            }

                            if (reader["name"] != DBNull.Value)
                            {
                                companyName = (string)reader["name"];

                            }

                            company.Add(companyGuid, companyName);
                            companies.Add(company);
                        }
                    };
                };
                    


            };

            return companies;
                
        }
    }
}
```

I am unsure where I went wrong in printing the entire list from the dictionary.  I am getting my keys and values from a connection string in a SQL database. I need to print the entire list of companies and I am only getting one when I run the code. Any ideas where I went wrong? I am a beginner coder in C#.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please see this link for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018114/read-data-from-sqldatareader

Answer (score 1):

You are only reading once. If you [read the documentation for the SqlDataReader class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) the provide an example that is as follows and requires a while loop.

```
  using (SqlConnection connection =
               new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command =
            new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        // Call Read before accessing data.
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ReadSingleRow((IDataRecord)reader);
        }

        // Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems with this code.

- You are initializing `companies` with `new List<Dictionary<Guid, string>>()` but you are discarding this value immediately afterwards and replace it by `GetCompanies()`.
- You are using a dictionary which is supposed to hold key/value pairs but you always only adding one key value pair to it. You could simply use a tuple `(Guid id, string name)` for this purpose instead of a wasted collection. Or better: Create a record type `record Company(Guid Id, string Name);`. Then you would use a `List<Company>`. Then adding a company becomes:

  ```cs
  companies.Add(new(companyGuid, companyName));
  ```
- You are not looping through the query result and moving to the next record. Therefore you are only getting the first one. Use `while (rdr.Read()) { add the companies to the list here }`. You can then drop the `if (reader.HasRows)` because `rdr.Read()` returns a Boolean which is `true` only when there is a row available.
- You are assigning a default value to variables when it is not necessary. Use a ternary operator instead and write

  ```cs
  Guid companyGuid =
       reader["id"] == DBNull.Value ? new Guid() : (Guid)reader["id"];
  string companyName =
       reader["name"] == DBNull.Value ? String.Empty : (string)reader["name"];
  ```
- You are creating the `SqlCommand` with `new SqlCommand(query, conn)` but then you assign the `query` again unnecessarily with `cmd.CommandText = query;`. This constructor assigns the command type `CommandType.Text` automatically. So, you can drop this assignment as well.
- Don't write a semicolon (`;`) after an end brace (`}`).
- `new Guid()` creates an empty Guid structure (`[00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]`). If you want to generate a new Guid, use `Guid.NewGuid()`.

---

**Suggested implementation**

- We declare:

  ```cs
  record Company(Guid Id, string Name);
  ```

  Records override `ToString` to display the values in a pleasant way automatically.
- We can use file-scoped names spaces to save horizontal space.
- We can use using-var statements instead of the structured using-statements to save even more space and make the code easier to read. These usings extend automatically to the end of the current code block (i.e. to the end of the method in our case).
- We can assign the values from the database to a temp local.

```cs
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SECDataPurge;

internal class Program
{
    record Company(Guid Id, string Name);

    static void Main()
    {
        List<Company> companies = GetCompanies();
        foreach (Company company in companies) {
            Console.WriteLine(company);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static List<Company> GetCompanies()
    {
        var companies = new List<Company>();

        using var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppDbConnectionString"]);
        string query = "SELECT id, [name] FROM [dbo].[company];";
        using var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();

        using var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read()) {
            object id = reader["id"];
            object name = reader["name"];

            Guid companyGuid = id == DBNull.Value ? Guid.NewGuid() : (Guid)id;
            string companyName = name == DBNull.Value ? String.Empty : (string)name;
            companies.Add(new(companyGuid, companyName));
        }
        return companies;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation, very helpful for me. I am just learning C#.

Comment: You are welcome. Also, since you are new to StackOverflow, I would like to inform you that you can upvote good answers and accept the answer that helped you the most by checking the tick mark next to the Answer. On this site an upvote or an accepted answer counts as a "thanks".